# Code snippets for MongoDB using .NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, code-snippets

Can anyone suggest some basic operations and connectivity code snippets for MongoDB with .NET? It would be great if they used C# too.

Comment: check out this screencast http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJBo3uHUW3o

Comment: Be aware that this video is old and is not about the official C# driver which is newer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the official [C# Driver Tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial).

There's also a 10gen webinar [Introduction to the new official C# Driver](http://www.10gen.com/webinars/csharp), that has all the essentials:

- DLLs and namespaces
- BSON object model
- Server, Database and Collection classes
- Query and update methods
- Query builders
- Cursors
- Fields, SortBy and other option builders
- Serialization support for POCOs
- Customizing serialization
- Replica set support
- GridFS